# Should I be worried about thread safety when using pymongo driver?

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, concurrency

I am writing a function to only insert into mongodb if a document with a particular identity doesn't exist.

e.g.

```
def insertOnlyIfNew(document, the_collection):
"""
:param the_collection: mongodb collection
"""
    pass
```

I plan to implement this by doing a find for the document's identifier (the identifier is not the `ObjectId`). If it does not exist, only then will I call

```
the_collection.insert(document)
```

I am using CPython 2.7.5 & pymongo. Since the GIL is in effect, I can safely ignore race conditions. Right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong. =) Between the time that your application executes find() and the time you attempt to insert a document, several things can happen:

1. If your application is multithreaded, another thread can modify the MongoDB collection. (Python releases the GIL while waiting for a network response.)
2. Another process, perhaps on another machine, could connect to MongoDB and alter the collection.

But in this case your requirements are easily satisfied. [Create a unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the field that must be unique. Whenever your application attempts to insert a document, if one already exists with the same identifier, PyMongo will raise DuplicateKeyError:

```
try:
    the_collection.insert(document)
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
    print 'caught DuplicateKeyError'
```

Comment: This is good advice. In my case, I will create a unique compound index. Thanks